# ember.js how to handle ManyToMany relations creating?

Tags: php, ember.js, many-to-many

Let's say that in my backend I have models `Dealer` and `Car`, both are connected with `ManyToMany` relation also in Ember. I can create relations  manually in backend and then while displaying it with Ember views I can easily display that `Dealer X` has `Car 1`, `Car 2` and `Car 3` in his offer. Also when displaying the `Car` I can display all `Dealers` who contains the `Car` model.

Now I need to add some editing possibility, I mean that for an example when I'm editing the `Car` I'd like to choose the `Dealers` who has this `Car` in his offer. (I need the possibility of such edit only for one side of relation - not both, so just can accept that Im able to add `Dealers` to `Cars` but don't need to do that in the opposite direction (that's exactly how my background is working)

So in `App.CarController` I created an actions like `addDealerToCar` and `deleteDealerFromCar` and they sends proper queries to backend which  saves the relations.

Question is: how can I make some field, which will allow me to choose the `Dealer` ie. using a selectbox or other dropdown and then call an action which will send in to backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently implemented adding many-to-many relations in a form by using checkboxes.  This was suitable for my use case because I only would have between two and six Dealerships that you could choose from for a particular Car. If you have more than that though, this probably isn't suitable.

Here is the code I used translated to your scenario. I took inspiration from the code in this question: [Many to Many Relationships with Ember, ember-data and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624193/many-to-many-relationships-with-ember-ember-data-and-rails)

View:

```
App.CarEditView = Ember.View.extend({

  dealerCheckbox: Ember.Checkbox.extend({

    init: function(){
      this._super();
      var self = this;
      // start off with the checkboxes checked for any dealer that
      // has this car already
      this.get('car.dealers').forEach(function(dealer){
        if(dealer.get('id') == self.get('dealer.id')){
          self.set('checked', true);
        }
      });

    },

    checkedObserver: (function(){
      var car = this.get('car');
      if(this.get('checked'))
        car.addDealerToCar(this.get('dealer'));
      else
        car.deleteDealerFromCar(this.get('dealer'));
    }).observes('checked')

  })

});
```

Template (this would be part of the form to edit a Car):

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Required Signatures</label>

  <div class="controls">
    {{#each dealer in controller.allDealers}}
      <label class="checkbox">

        {{view view.dealerCheckbox
          carBinding="controller.content"
          dealerBinding="dealer"
        }}
        {{dealer.title}}

      </label>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And you would need to add something like this to make the above code work so that you can access a list of all the Dealers.

```
App.CarEditRoute = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('allDealers', App.Dealer.find());
  }

});
```