# Ember data and support for many-to-many relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm asking this question because I found this question but I'm wondering if it's still relevant.

[Many to Many Relationships with Ember, ember-data and Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624193/many-to-many-relationships-with-ember-ember-data-and-rails)

Does ember data natively support saving of many-to-many relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it Does. You can see in [that part](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/models/relationships/#toc_many-to-many) of the docs.

```
// app/models/post.js
  export default DS.Model.extend({
      tags: DS.hasMany('tag')
  });

// app/models/tag.js
  export default DS.Model.extend({
      posts: DS.hasMany('post')
  });
```

You have to see what your Adapter is doing when serializing the data. If you need, you can create a [custom serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/).